# How to use address of function in function pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

My following code is working fine. But I have little doubt, please see `//Comment1` and `//Comment2`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct PTR
{
    int (*funptr)(int);
};

int fun1(int)
{
    printf("Fun1\n");
    return 0;
}

int fun2(int)
{
    printf("Fun2\n");
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    PTR p;
    p.funptr = &fun1; //Comment1
    p.funptr(5);

    printf("\n");

    p.funptr = fun2; //Comment2
    p.funptr(5);


  return 0;

}
```

Output : Fun1
Fun2

There is no problem in output.

At comment1 '&' opertor is used, so we are expllicing telling to get address, in comment2, we are not using '&', so which one is correct way?

Comment: How can you declare PTR p in main function without using struct name or typedef?

Comment: @RaghuSrikanthReddy PTR is name of structure. (struct PTR)

Comment: But, Did this code compile? You neither typecasted nor used struct before PTR.

Comment: @RaghuSrikanthReddy Code is compiled using Visual Studio. And there should not be any reason not to compile this code. You are creating Structure PTR ,and using it. Just to clarify, is it necessary in C++ to typedef a class, no. And class and struct are very same just with one little difference.

Comment: I compiled this code using gcc. and this question is tagged C, not C++.

Comment: @RaghuSrikanthReddy Right now my virtual machine's Ubuntu not working, but whats the problem, why I need to typedef struct?

Comment: @RaghuSrikanthReddy I used extern "C" in my whole code, and working without problem. So both C/C++ way it is working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45285/discussion-between-raghu-srikanth-reddy-and-rockstartprogrammer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'&' is optional when taking the address of function。

Answer (score 1):

Here,

`p.funptr = &fun1` we are giving the address of the function. So '&' here is optional as `p.funptr = fun1` also assign address of function.